# how can i know the physical path from selected file (fileupload bootstrap)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller, file-upload

I´m making a web application in MVC, I have a view where I select a file from my pc directory (like opendialog form in windows applications), bootstrap´s fileupload gets the file name but I want to know his physical path to. Because I want to save it in my data base (where file come from).

Anybody can help me??

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, this information is never sent to the server for obvious security reasons. Only the filename is sent to the server. So you cannot store the physical path where the file originated from the client machine on your server.

Comment: thank you both! Darin Dimitrov and Steve Fenton one more question related to this, because I think I asked the question the other way (sorry). what I really want is to select a path where I save a file (for example), I can save that path?? Or can not?

Comment: You could save the file on the server. For example if you wanted to save it in the `~/App_Data` folder you could use the `Server.MapPath("~/App_Data")` to get the physical path to that folder on the server. And then concatenate it with the filename that is coming from the client. Look at the following blog post: http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx

Answer (score 0):

When you upload a file via a web browser, the actual file path is not supplied. This is seen as being a security feature.

There is no way to circumvent this using pure HTML. Some people get around it by using a plugin such as Flash or Silverlight to upload the file, but I recommend living with this feature if you can.

Comment: thank you both! Darin Dimitrov and Steve Fenton

one more question related to this, because I think I asked the question the other way (sorry).
what I really want is to select a path where I save a file (for example), I can save that path?? Or can not?